# Is it possible to schedule sending a VF Page via Email?

Tags: apex-email-service, schedulebatch, vf-email-template, visualforce

We have this requirement that says we need to schedule once a month the sending of a VF page that contains custom dashboard charts via email.

So if we break this requirement down, we need to do the following:

1 - Create a VF page that contains customed dashboard charts (standard dashboards couldn't support our requirement due to filtering issues)

2 - Add the VF page to an Account

3 - Create a batch class that will schedule the sending of this VF page to corresponding email recipients (as given by the shop email set in each Account) via Email.

(1) & (2) can be done. We already have an existing requirement that also applies the exact behavior for a separate subsidiary.

However, we are not sure if (3) is even possible. My doubts are the ff:

1 - how does one send a VF page as an email without opening the page to get a screenshot to be then emailed to the corresponding recipient?

2 - is it possible to retrieve the custom dashboard charts in the VF page and then convert it to a pdf that we can then send to the corresponding recipient?

All answers are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Conceptually, PageReference.getContentAsPDF should work, but I haven't tested this. It should be simple enough to test, though.

Comment: ok thanks, we'll check on this. however, do we need to have an open tab of the VF page for this to work?

Comment: No, it's not necessary, as the PDF can be generated without it.